# How to handle permissions in GAE application

Tags: google-app-engine

I am developing an application on GAE in JSP. We have a private domain with Google Apps for Business, that means that the application is only available for members of my organization. However I would like to restrict that permissions so that only certain users can access the app. Even better I would like to create roles. Unfortunately from the Domain Admin page I am not able to define permissions for the GAE application. Is there something I am missing? Do I have to handle them manually? If so, how? The only thing that came to my mind is a Spreadsheet where I save the permissions but that's not so clever... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed that for a closed business application and wrote custom code.  The Java design had an [Access Control List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) per securable object.  Each ACL was saved as a single String for least Datastore overhead and reconstructed on demand.  Resource access was guarded with something like:

```
if (resource.permissions.granted(user, operation) {
    // do the operation
} else {
    // send an informative 'access denied' response
}
```

Comment: So you would suggest using DataStore rather than a Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes for the following reasons.  AppEngine runs directly on top of Datastore so access is efficient.  Its API is simple and its scalability is huge.  Its schemaless structure (or application defined schema if you implement one) is more flexible than the rigid (sheet, row, column) structure of a spreadsheet.

Comment: Good catch, you were right and it is actually easy. I was able to implement it in a half an hour (at least for a single page). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Google Groups to define app roles. Once you've authenticated the user you can read their group memberships to determine which roles they should be given for your app.

Comment: Is there any wat to retrieve user membership through the UserService class or do I have to go through Google Groups API?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you'll have to deal with the roles and stuff manually.

From Google App Engine point of view there is a way to restrict your app to only users from the Google Apps domain, by changing the **Authentication Type** from the **Application Settings**, but FYI you won't be able to change it back.

Also there is way to restrict certain URLs to only to the admins of the app and the admins are the ones that are on the list in the **Permissions** page from the Dashboard.

I never done it using Java but you can read more about in the [Deployment Descriptor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication).

Having said that it's very limited on what you can achieve and if you want to have more roles or doing more specific tasks per logged in user you'll have to implement these things yourself. Keeping track of the logged in users and assigning roles to them within the app and based on who is logged in allowing or not performing tasks.